# Prevent $scope variable copy from listening to its original

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my AngularJS app, I generally pass data using the `$rootScope`. In the various states, I manipulate pull them into $scope when necessary. But since $scope has prototypical inheritance, I suppose this is just for readability and not much else. In my app, there are the following variables...

```
$rootScope.list // object
$rootScope.list.items // array
$rootScope.additions // array
$rootScope.cart // object
$rootScope.cart.items // array
```

Before I begin, this is generally laid out in pseudocode. So if it's not correct, that's okay. I'm looking for a conceptual understanding.

At first, the cart is empty. You look at `list.items` and copy individual list items into the `cart.items` array. This works great, until we start talking about duplicate items with unique `additions`.

Say, I wanted to have 2 of the same item, except one item has different additions (cart items have a quantity property, not list items).

```
$rootScope.cart.items = [
   {
      name: 'listItem1',
      quantity: 3,
      additions: ['addition1']
   }, {
      name: 'listItem2',
      quantity: 1,
      additions: ['addition2']
   }, {
      name: 'listItem1', // same as cart.items[1], but additions has diff values
      quantity: 1,
      additions: ['addition1','addition2']
   }];
```

Firstly, AngularJS complained because there were duplicates in my ng-repeater. I resolved that issue by appending `track by $index` in the `ng-repeat` directive. It was also the first red flag I saw that told me I was doing something wrong.

My first idea was to create a temporary `cartItem`, arbitrarily add its additions, then push it onto `$rootScope.cart.items[]`. But when it's time to push the 3rd cart item onto the cart, which is another copy of the 1st list item, it overwrites the `additions[]` of the first cart item. So, `$rootScope.cart.items` looks like this:

```
$rootScope.cart.items = [
   {
      name: 'listItem1',
      quantity: 3,
      additions: ['addition1','addition2']
   }, {
      name: 'listItem2',
      quantity: 1,
      additions: ['addition2']
   }, {
      name: 'listItem1', // same as cart.items[1], but additions has diff values
      quantity: 1,
      additions: ['addition1','addition2']
   }];
```

From this result, it's ostensibly pass-by-reference when it comes to copying $rootScope variables from one place to another.

So, my next thought was to try using a directive with an isolate scope. But I realized soon enough that my logic was faulty. While an isolate scope would give me one-way data-binding, it wasn't in the direction I was hoping for. The scope parent to the directive would still be able to set values.

What I would ideally like to do is arbitrarily add list.items to cart.items. But any cart items that come from the same list item, I would like to be unbound from each other. Thus, additions in one copy can be different from additions in another copy. **What would be the best way to achieve this?** I have a feeling it might have been a poor decision to use `$rootScope` to pass data between states in my app, though it is the fastest way I have found.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy -- This will help you with making copies of arrays. Also, yes, you should try to not use rootScope, there is always another way. In your case, you can use a factory

Comment: Great, I presume that would make `$rootScope.cart.items` a shallow copy of `$rootScope.list.items`. If you want to make an answer out of this, I'd greatly appreciate it! The more elaboration, the better.

Comment: Right, just referring to my previous implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular copy is what you are looking for.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

There are a couple methods to use this that you will see in the docs, but my coworkers and I have found better use out using the optional 'destination' option.

So this is how it works

First setup your new target array.

```
var newArray = [];
```

Then you use that as the destination in angular copy

```
angular.copy(firstArray, newArray);
```

There you go, it is just that easy!

Now your new array will no longer be connected to the original array.

I would also look into using factories as services for your code instead of using rootScope. Learning that will increase your productivity a ton and make your code a lot more readable and user friendly. Here is a good article about it.

http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/

**Edit**

And as someone mentioned in the comments, it is indeed a deep copy. That means it will copy all children objects and arrays inside of an array.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the `additions` of your first cart item, you actually edit the `additions` of both the first and third cart items, because they are the same.

When you create the third cart item, instead, you could copy the properties of the first one:

```
var newCartItem = {};

newCartItem.name = firstCartitem.name;
newCartItem.quantity = firstCartitem.quantity;
// Do not point to the other array, instead create a new one and copy over
newCartItem.additions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < firstCartitem.additions.length; i++) {
  newCartItem.additions.push( firstCartitem.additions[i] );
}
// Now you can add anything to the new cart item without editing the first one
```